# Does creating too many objects in javascript will affect the performance?

Tags: arrays, performance, object, javascript

I am developing a web app and creating many objects in JavaScript, which I need to maintain throughout the session or when the website is open and I am making all objects referencing to a single global object. Will it affect the performance of webb app?

```
var Obj1 = somethig;
var obj200 = something;
window.global.Obj1 = Obj1;
window.global.Obj200 = Obj200;
```

Comment: "Too many" implies more than is needed, which is a problem in, and of, itself

Comment: Notice that the code snippet you've shown does *not create* any object. It just assigns variables and properties to point to already existing ones.

Comment: I suppose that `something` is an object literal.

Answer (score 11):

Disclaimer: I'm a software engineer on the Chakra Javascript engine in Internet Explorer 9 and later (Hello from Building 18!)

In short: "it depends" - we need to know how many objects you're creating, how complex they are (as JavaScript does not have classes, but prototypes and instances), how frequently you're creating them, and if your script/program would cause the GC to collect the objects (and GC runs aren't pretty).

Some tips:

1. If you're storing lots of simple data objects, use an array to take advantage of whatever optimizations the runtime will have. And if you are using an array, ensure all of the elements have the same underlying type (e.g. don't mix JavaScript objects with numbers in the same array).
2. JavaScript is garbage-collected - which means it has all of the downsides associated with it, including pausing the entire script execution while the GC runs. If a lot of objects become available for collection all at once then the GC pause will run for a while. Watch out for memory fragmentation too.
3. Avoid instance properties (i.e. use prototype properties or constructor properties), i.e.:

Bad:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
    var foo = { baz: function() { return 5; } };
    foo.bar();
}
```

Good:

```
function Foo() { } // `Foo` constructor.

Foo.prototype.baz = function() { return 5; };

for(var i=0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
    var foo = new Foo();
    foo.bar();
}
```

Also good:

```
 function Foo() { } 

 Foo.baz = function(foo) { return 5; };

 for(var i=0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
    var foo = new Foo();
    Foo.bar( foo );
 }
```

As for your code example, if you're in the root scope (called `global`, which in browsers is aliased by the `window` object) then the `var` keyword has the effect of making a property. So this:

```
var Obj1 = somethig;
var obj200 = something;
window.Obj1 = Obj1; // there is no `window.global` object
window.Obj200 = Obj200;
```

...doesn't actually do anything: `var Obj1` *is* the same thing as `window.Obj1`.

Finally, a protip: only give Constructor functions `TitleCase` names, otherwise everything else (vars, parameters, locals, etc) `lowerCase` names. Calling an instance `Obj1` made my face twitch.

**As always, the golden rule applies: premature optimisation is the root of all evil** - profile your code *first* to see if there's a problem before making significant changes to your code (and IE 11's F12 tools are great for inspecting the memory and processing performance of your code, btw - not that I'm unbiased!).

Comment: It's also worth clarifying that a variable automatically becomes a property of **window** even if you don't use the `var` keyword, which is actually a lot worse, especially inside functions. Additionally, variables declared using the `var` keyword cannot be deleted: `var x=7; delete x;` would fail, where `y=3; delete y;` would succeed in deleting the variable and therefore GCing it.

Comment: @istos use of the `delete` operator only removes a property from its parent object; it does not necessarily trigger a GC, nor make memory available for GC, nor is it necessary for the GC to collect an object in the first place. Needlessly `delete`ing properties is just wasting cycles.

Comment: So if I have some object in memory, which is a property of **window**, and the deletion succeeds, what happens to that object?

Comment: @istos if any other object holds a reference to the value held by the deleted property then it will remain in memory. If the GC is certain that there are no strong-references to the object (compare with weak-references, e.g. WeakMap) then it will be collected and the memory freed. GC passes happen non-deterministically, and are not triggered by `delete` operations.

Comment: Intriguing! Thanks for clarifying. I don't have a CS background but based on what you've described, it looks like the variable `y` in my example should be collected since nothing else references it, correct? 

Also, if deleting properties is wasting cycles, then how would you **delete** a property? It seems to me that there are valid cases when you need to actually `delete` a property and simply setting it to `null` isn't enough - though that would be for reasons unrelated to GC. 

It's good to know that GC isn't triggered directly by the `delete` operator; thanks for that info!