# JSON takes too much memory on Safari

Tags: javascript, json, memory, memory-management, safari

I have a JSON object which is about 5MB in file format. However it seems 900 MB on Safari(it takes less memory in other browsers like chrome). Structure of this JSON is like a regular JSON object. Here is my Json :

It is like

```
var a = {
   x: {
       2168: {
             b: {
                1746741:{
                  d:{ 
                    "1: {},
                    "2: {},
                    "3: {},
                    "4: {},
                    "5: {},
                    "6: {},
                  }
               }
              ... almost 50 items...
           }
           ... almost 20 items...
       }
      ... almost 1000 items...
   }
}
```

Why this Json takes huge memory on Safari and how can i solve this problem? (It takes 900 MB on the first page request and adds up 900 MB more on each page request until browser crash.)

(I noticed that in a big JSON objects, using array is more effective is there any way to decrease usage of memory in browsers without using arrays in a JSON object ?)

Comment: What are you doing that requires parsing this much data in the browser? If you can't change the structure, you will need to use pagination to split the objects up and only load the data you need.

Comment: Parsing this json makes more than 5 million objects, I highly doubt you actually need all of them.

Comment: I would say whatever is returning your JSON probably a web service call should pass filter constraints on via http headers.

Comment: this happens from simply doing a `JSON.parse(yourJSON)`? As it sounds like something else is causing memory consumption. If you arent just doing a simple json parse you need to provide exactly what your code is doing

Comment: Actually, using too much data is not my decision and I can't change it right now because of time

Comment: Changing my dic objects to array like [2168, 2169 ....] or [1746741, 1746742 ,] decrease memory consumption to 200 MB, I just did not understand why ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does creating too many objects in javascript will affect the performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27143720/does-creating-too-many-objects-in-javascript-will-affect-the-performance)

Comment: @Omn I know using array much more better than this situation, just right now I want   to find a way today

Comment: What you have is an object literal, it's not valid JSON.

Comment: @RobG why it is not valid ? and what is the effect of this ?

Comment: JSON is a notation for objects that copies the object notation used in javascript (see [*JSON.org*](http://json.org)). It has no bearing on your question, I'm just pointing out an error in your terminology.

Comment: @Patrick Evans  even without JSON.parse function, with  an empty html file and a javascript instance includes a JSON Object which I mentioned on the question. After a couple refreshes safari is crashing.

Comment: @KnowGe your last comment seems like a [mcve], which is good for the question to be reopened. I would expect the actual version of Safari you are using, though, and the exact javascript code you are using, if it's more than `var a = ...;`